# How can I check in Fortran if a REAL was passed as DOUBLE?

Tags: fortran, precision, fortran90

I'm linking one subroutine to another calling program in Fortran. I don't have access to the calling program. The calling program passes my program either single precision numbers or double precision numbers depending on the user input switches. For example, here's some code

```
subroutine myCode( x )
 implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
 ! do something with x
end subroutine myCode
```

Again, the calling program may pass `x` as a single precision number of as a double precision number. I would like my program to fail if `x` was passed as a single precision number. The value of "x" can be any positive real number.

Is there a way that I can test `x` to see if it's a single precision number or a double precision number?

Comment: use the function `kind(x)` : if `kind(x)==kind(1.)` then it is a single precision number elseif `kind(x)==kind(1.d)` then it is a double precision number.

Comment: There's no Fortran way: as soon as a default real is passed to the argument you no longer have a Fortran program.

Comment: Use modules. All subroutines should be placed in a module. The compiler can then check everything is passed correctly.

Comment: "I don't have access to the calling program".  I would take that to mean modules and explicit inferface features are not an option.

Comment: agentp is correct. I don't have access to modules and explicit interface features.

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do except perhaps heuristically check if the values are in some expected range. This situation typically occurs when interfacing with some proprietary commercial software -- If that's the case it might be worthwhile to say what it is.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to check what was actually passed in is to overload the procedure and test which one was called:

```
module kinds_mod
    use iso_fortran_env, only: real32, real64
    implicit none
    interface my_double
        module procedure my_double_r32, my_double_r64
    end interface

    public  :: my_double
    private :: my_double_r32, my_double_r64

contains

    function my_double_r32(val) result(d)
        real(kind=real32), intent(in) :: val
        real(kind=real32) :: d
        d = val * 2.0_real32
        print*, "called for 32 bit real"
    end function my_double_r32

    function my_double_r64(val) result(d)
        real(kind=real64), intent(in) :: val
        real(kind=real64) :: d
        d = val * 2.0_real64
        print*, "called for 64 bit real"
    end function my_double_r64

end module kinds_mod

program test_kinds
    use kinds_mod
    implicit none
    real :: r, r2
    double precision :: d, d2

    r = 2.0
    d = 4.0_8

    print*, "calling for single precision"
    r2 = my_double(r)
    print *, r, r2, kind(r)
    print*, "calling for double precision"
    d2 = my_double(d)
    print *, d, d2, kind(d)
end program test_kinds
```